# Hibernate and how to avoid name change of modals

Tags: java, hibernate, refactoring

I am using Hibernate for a few years but am not sure about the usage of Query and Criteria.

I understood, that one of Hibernate strengths are to control the field name in one place.
If I have the following code:

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
.add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") )
.add( Restrictions.between("weight", minWeight, maxWeight) )
.list();
```

What if I change "name" of the Cat in the java object?

Even when using refactor replace (like in Elipse) it will not detect the element as something that needs to be changed!

If so , how do you maintain the field names in Java?

Comment: Unit tests.I can not think of any other mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe type safe queries are not supported in Hibernate specific api. JPA 2 however has support for it. Read this: [Dynamic, typesafe queries in JPA 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/)

Comment: So it means that I can't use it with my current hibernate implementation?

Comment: @Odelya yes your option is to move to JPA 2

Comment: Can't hibernate be used as JPA implementation?

Comment: @Odelya Ofcourse you can. But you should use JPA 2 Criteria API.

Comment: Thanks. I used so far http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/ but I guess that I after viewing your solution - I will try to find another solution

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem in the past, and actually there's no way to have a typed and refactor resistant(change name) reference of a field in java, so is neither possible have a query builder that allow this, but i tried to build a implementation of a query builder that using some workaround try to allow you to write type safe and refactor resistant query, it's name is ObjectQuery and you can found some information about [here](http://www.objectquery.org).

let me know if it solve your use case !

obviously is nothing of standard so if you are looking to something of standard, is better JPA Typesafe but it not have the same power!